# Setting up default SSL site on IIS8

Tags: ssl, sni, iis-8

I have setup few websites on IIS8 all using the same wildcard SSL certificate. Some of the sites need to be accessible to older browsers and operating systems, therefore I cannot use the "Require Server Name Indication" option.

Since SNI is not supported by all devices, IIS is showing the following alert:

*"No default SSL site has been created. To support browsers without SNI capabilities, it is recommended to create a default SSL site."*

How do I create a default SSL site? The [closest article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx) I found is not very clear, and I have the feeling that there must be an easier solution.

Server details: *Windows Server 2012, IIS8, One external IP address*

Comment: I love how this is such a "Well, whaddaya want me to do about it?" message. Fortunately, serverfault has the answer, as usual.

Answer (score 53):

You could chose any of the websites hosted in IIS and uncheck SNI (Server Name Indication there. Check this below

[image]

Comment: You also need to clear the 'host name' field in order for it to act as the default SSL website. At least the warning on not having a default SSL site did not disappear until I did so, and the IIS8 guide on setting up multiple HTTPS sites described the same setup.

Comment: FYI, regarding the comment above, I personally didn't need to clear "Host name" field for the warning to disappear, just unticked Require SNI option. IIS 8.0.9200

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to uncheck it at this point, unless you have some special use case. All modern browsers [support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=sni).

Comment: I don't want to uncheck SNI, I just want to enable SNI capabilities with default SSL.

Comment: Do not forget to Restart the site... (as I did) if you want this to work :)

Answer (score 2):

**ts;dr: Ignore the warning.**

It's 2022 and I was surprised to see this warning in a recently stood up Windows 2019 Server running IIS 10. Based on all [major browsers supporting SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support) for over 10 years, I think it's safe to say that you can simply disregard this warning.

Answer (score -1):

If you currently have a * binding clear that out as well (and uncheck the require SNI box on that binding)

Comment: Doesn't * equal _any hostname_, which is exactly what we need here?